# How to display specific HTML code with python-requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests

How can you display specific HTML code with python-requests?
This is my code:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
print("Made by Zaseth.")
shodanURL = input("Your target IP: ")
s.get('https://www.shodan.io/host/' + shodanURL)
r = s.get('https://www.shodan.io/host/' + shodanURL)
print(r.text)
print(r)
print(r.headers)
print(r.status_code)
with open('output.txt','w') as fd:
fd.write(r.text)
```

Now this will add the users input on s.get and safe the full HTML response into output.txt which is all good, but my response is the full HTML page. I just want to display specific data on the page like:

```
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Ports open: 53, 80, 110, 143, 443, 465, 993, 995, 2082, 2083, 2087, 3306, 8080, 8443"/>
```

This is the tag where Shodan.io shows all the open ports.
Here is some more data I would like to get displayed:

```
<h2><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>the ip
<small style="padding-left:10px;">the host</small>
</h2><span class="badge badge-inverse">something special like Database</span>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` for scraping(Extracting data from HTML page). [Link for BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: why you want to scrap data? they have API  for python @  https://shodan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Well BeautifulSoup is the worst module ever. And @Gahan you are right.

Answer (score 0):

if the location of the row you want to retrieve is in a static state, then the easiest way in my opinion is to use split.

```py
line = 18 # html line you want to fetch
print(r.text.splitlines()[line - 1])
# <meta name="twitter:description" content="Ports open: 80, 443, 2079, 2082, 2086, 2087" />
```

another way with regex:

```
print(re.findall('(<meta name="twitter:description(.*)>)', r.text))
```